# Движения символа в конец строки

Tags: python

Столкнулся с задачей на кодеваре и вроде бы решил, если бы не одно но! Сама задача проста до безумия, нужна в списке все, что является  0(ноль) отправить в конец строки.
так работает

```
def move_zeros(array):
    for i in array:
        array.append(array.pop(array.index(0)))
        if array.index != 0:
            continue
    print(array)
# [9, -10, {}, True, 1, 2, 'a', 1, 1, [], None, 3, 'z', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Но до тех пор, пока в данные не подсунуть False

```
if array.index != 0 and array.index is False:
```

все равно получаю, что то типа

```
[9, -10, {}, True, 1, 2, 'a', 1, 1, [], None, 3, 'z', 1, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from math import isclose    

l = [.0, .001, -.0, 9, -10, {}, True, 1, 2, 'a', 1, 1, [], None, 3, 'z', 1, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def iszero(val):
    return val is 0 or (isinstance(val, float) and isclose(val, 0))

# подсчет количества нулей
zeros_cnt = sum(map(iszero, l))

# фильтрация списка от нулей:
l = [i for i in l if not iszero(i)]

# вставка нулей в конец списка
l += [0] * zeros_cnt
```

Comment: Спасибо, пашет! но если подсунуть 0.0 то облом

Comment: @Vadim, обновил ответ.